# Dereferencing an Array of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this simple dereferencing statement.

I've tried printing `**names`, and then I get what I expect to get from `*names -- 'C'`. However, `*names` gives me `'D'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
   char *names[] = {"Carl", "David", "Gibson", "Long", "Paul"};
   printf("%c\n", *names);

   return 0;
}
```

The console prints out `'D'`. I'm not sure why the resulting `char` from `*names` is not the first letter of the first item, `'C'`.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour due to using the wrong format specifier -- modern compilers will warn about this. Examples of correct code include `printf("%s\n", *names);` or `printf("%c\n", **names);`

Comment: turning on / reading the warnings is also a good idea

Comment: The `%c` format specifier expects a single character (an integer argument to `printf`).  The `%s` format specifier expects a string (a `char *`).  You're passing a `char *` to a `%c` specifier, which makes no sense.  Your compiler should have warned about this (make sure your code is clear of warnings before posting here, unless you truly don't understand the warning, in which case that should be the title of your post).

Comment: If you _did_ want to stick with your current method, you could try, for example: `printf("%c\n", (*(names[1]+(sizeof(char)*2))));` where the `1` represents the second name in the array, and the `2` represents the letter within the name.  This would output `v` from `David`.  Or alternatively, just use `%s` ;).

Comment: @AndyJ leave the `sizeof` out, pointer arithmetic already scales by the element size.  The only reason it isn't blowing up in your face is that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: compiling the posted code results in the message; *untitled.c:7:13: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]*  for the line: *printf("%c\n", *names);*  This is a serious problem

Comment: `*names` is equivalent to `names[0]`, so gives a pointer to the first character of the string `"Carl"`.   So `printf("%c\n", *names)` is equivalent to `printf("%c\n", "Carl")`.   The `%c` format specifier causes `printf()` to expect a single character as the corresponding argument.  `"Carl"` is an array of `char`, which will be passed as a pointer to `printf()` - either way, `printf()` does not receive a single character as that argument.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior and the output varies with the compiler.
When I run this with gcc, there is no output. Using `**names` prints 'C'.
The undefined behavior is because of the wrong format specifier. You use `%c`, but `*names` point to the first element in the array, ie a char array storing "Carl".
Use the `%s` format specifier to print strings.

```c
printf("%c\n", *names);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you compile this code, GCC will give you the following:

```
test.c:5:12: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%c\n", *names);
           ~^     ~~~~~~
           %s
```

So you're basically trying to print the first character of the first name, but instead of passing a `char` as an argument, your're passing a pointer to char. What you could do is this:

```
printf("%c\n", *names[0]);
```

in which you specify that you want the first character from the first element.

Also, using `**names` is the same as using `*names[0]`